# MySQL different database location

Tags: arch-linux, mysql, mariadb

I do not have enough space on my root partition to store the database.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroRoot   29G   21G  6.4G  77% /
dev                                1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
run                                1.9G  852K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                              1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              1.9G  596K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroHome  197G   54G  133G  29% /home
/dev/sda1                          247M   88M  147M  38% /boot
tmpfs                              383M  8.0K  383M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Changing datadir in my.`cnf` to a new location caused a permission problem ([Warning] Can't create test file `/home/u/tmp/mysql/acpfg.lower-test`
)

How is it possible change the directory where MariaDB/MySQL stores the database under Linux (for example to /home/u/tmp/mysql)?

Comment: For an unknown reason, moving the data to another partition did not work either.

So for a quick fix, instead of messing with llvm or gparted, I reduced my `/swapfile` size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either reconfigure MySQL to look for the data directory in a different location, or bind mount a new location over the original.

Make sure that the `mysql` service is stopped before you carry out these changes.

Then, move all the files and sub-directories from the original location into your new location.

**Reconfigure MySQL**

edit `/etc/my.cnf` and change `datadir` to:

```
datadir=/home/u/tmp/mysql
```

or...

**Bind Mount**

Use a bind mount to mount your new location over the original:

```
mount --bind /home/u/tmp/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Once you're happy that everything works, edit your `/etc/fstab` to make it permanent:

```
/home/u/tmp/mysql /var/lib/mysql  none  bind 0 0
```

**File Permissions**

Regardless of which method you choose, you'll need to ensure that the permissions on your new location are correct, as follows:

The top level directory (`/home/u/tmp/mysql`) and everything below should be owned by user and group `mysql` (assuming `mysql` runs as these on Arch Linux):

```
# chown -R mysql. /home/u/tmp/mysql
```

All files are:

```
# find /home/u/tmp/mysql/ -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
```

All directories are:

```
# find /home/u/tmp/mysql/* -type d -exec chmod 0700 {} \;
```

The top level directory is:

```
# chmod 0755 /home/u/tmp/mysql
```

Comment: datadir in /etc/mysql/my.cnf is causing an [Warning] Can't create test file /home/u/tmp/mysql/acpfg.lower-test. The same problem I get also with mount --bind /home/u/tmp/mysql /var/lib/mysql. Is necessary to change permission or groups?

Comment: Yes, the permissions on the new directory must be identical to the old. If you're using SELinux then you must relabel the new directory too.

Comment: Which is best way to copy the old permission to the new directory?

Comment: Also, it should be worth mentioning that the `mysql` service needs to be stopped before doing the changes.

Comment: @garethTheRed, yeah. However, even before the reconfiguration of `my.cnf` it is better to stop the service :)

Comment: I stopped the service before changing my.cnf. While trying to start the service again I got [Warning] Can't create test file /home/u/tmp/mysql/acpfg.lower-test. I do not how to change the permsions.

Comment: Check what `ls -l /home/u/tmp/mysql` shows. It should show that it's owned by `mysql` user/group (if not, run the `chown` command above) and the permissions should be `rwxr-xr-x` (if not, run the last `chmod` command above).

Comment: I changed the permissions, but I still get the same warning. $ ls -ahl /home/u/tmp/mysql
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql    mysql    4.0K 23.08.2014 20:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 u        u        4.0K 23.08.2014 20:02 ../

Comment: I don't use SELinux. umask -S shows these u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx.

Comment: Permissions might have been changed since the directory tree was created. What does `namei -l /home/u/tmp/mysql` show?

Comment: $ namei -l /home/u/tmp/mysql <br/>
f: /home/u/tmp/mysql <br/>
drwxr-xr-x root     root     / <br/>
drwxr-xr-x root     root     home <br/>
drwx------ u        u        u <br/>
drwxr-xr-x u        u        tmp <br/>
drwxr-xr-x mysql    mysql    mysql <br/>

Comment: `/home` is set to `0700`.  Mine is `0755`.  Try setting yours to `0755`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped, but now I got [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. Executing mysql_upgrade I got Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory"). I needed space and deleted /var/lib/mysql, but pacman reinstalled the packages, but did not created /var/lib/mysql. It seems I do not have mysql.sock on my system.

Comment: Solved, the above error by mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/home/u/tmp/mysql. However, I got a new one: [Error] mysqld: File './mysql-bin.000204' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16663/discussion-between-gareththered-and-user977828).

Answer (score 1):

Settings like this go into the MySQL configuration file (e.g. in /etc/mysql/my.cnf; the exact location depends on your system). The setting in question is datadir, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir for more info.